# java - use of extend

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the use of extend in Java.

from this code:

There is a superclass with a printMethode

Here is a subclass, called Subclass, that overrides printMethod():

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    // overrides printMethod in Superclass
    public void printMethod() {
        super.printMethod();
        System.out.println("Printed in Subclass");
    }
}
```

1. Can we use to extend the printMethod, without the super?

   ```
   @Override 
   public void printMethod() {
       System.out.println("Printed in Subclass");
   }
   ```
2. what is the use of `super.printMethod()` in the body of the extended printMethod ?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The call to super.printMethod calls the parent class's version.  Sometimes that's appropriate, sometimes it isn't.  The only function that MUST call the superclass version is a constructor.

Comment: A child class constructor doesn't have to call `super()`.

Comment: Eclipse refuses to comiple every time I don't.  I'll see if I can find the exact rule.

Comment: To be specific-  you must call a version of super in a constructor if your parent has no 0 parameter constructor.  If it does and you don't call super, the 0 parameter version is assumed.

Comment: although in java, if you have a subclass method of the same name as a superclass method it will automatically override it, many IDEs will complain if you do not use the @override notation

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes.
2. It calls the method `printMethod()` of the parent class. Sometimes there is common functionality for the classes, but each child has to do something specific also. In this case, it is convenient to put it the common part in the parent class, and call super from the child classes.

Answer (score 1):

in here the super keyword extends the parent class method ...

if you have code format like this

```
class grandfather { name() }
class father extends { name() }
class son extends father
{ 
  super.name() 
}
```

this super.name actually calls name method from the class grandfather...
hope this helped